# In the axioms of a coalgebra, does the *naturalness* of the isomorphisms play any role?

Tags: category-theory, coalgebras, natural-transformations

[image]

I don't know whether this question makes complete sense, but I'm 90% certain it does.

In the definition of a coalgebra over a field, the fact that $(C \otimes C) \otimes C \cong C \otimes (C \otimes C)$ is a *natural* isomorphism enables the two to be equated. But do we *need* the naturalness, or can we settle for an unnatural isomorphism?

Similarly, the duality functor on $k$-FinVec reverses the directions of all the arrows (because it's contravariant). Write the duality functor as $(-)^*$. Does the fact that the isomorphism $(C \otimes C)^* \cong C^* \otimes C^*$ is *natural* play any important role in the fact that every finite-dimensional coalgebra is dual to a finite-dimensional algebra. If we drop naturalness, then $(C \otimes C)^* \cong C^* \otimes C^*$ is true simply because of dimension counting. So why can't we use the existence of an (unnatural) isomorphism alone? Does it have something to do with the morphisms of the form $\operatorname{id}\otimes \Delta$, and the way that $\otimes$ is combining two morphisms together?

Comment: You wrote «…is a natural isomorphism…» but the correct phrase is «…is *the* natural isomorphism…»: it has to be the usual canonical map. (Canonical and natural are different things! The canonical map is natural, but in general there may be many natural isomorphisms, while the canonical is unique: being canonical means that *we* chose it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, one can define what a coalgebra is on any tensor category. Such a thing is an abelian category $C$ endowed with a bifunctor $\otimes:C\times C\to C$, such that there is an object $\mathbf1$, and natural isomorphisms $a:(X\otimes Y)\otimes Z\to X(\otimes Y\otimes Z)$, $l:X\otimes\mathbb1\to X$, and $r:\mathbb1\otimes X\to X$ that satiasfy certain conditions. Notice that these maps are what you need to define a coalgebra, as you wrote.

The point is that an abelian category may have several different tensor structures, tuples $(\otimes,\mathbb1,a,l,r)$ that satisfy the needed conditions, and it may well be the case that what being coalgebra in $C$ with respect to a tensor structure be very different from what a coalgebra in $C$ with respect to another tensor structure.

It is very often the case that on an abelian category $C$ there are two tensor structures $(\otimes,\mathbb1,a,l,r)$ and $(\otimes',\mathbb1',a',l',r')$ which only differ in that $a$ and $a'$ are different, for example. That is why the map $a$, called the associator, is important.

It is not difficult to construct examples of this. For example, the category $C$ of vector spaces endowed with a grading over a group $G$ has many different tensor structures corresponding to $3$-cocycles $G\times G\times G\to K^\times$ with values in the multiplicativ group of the ground field. This is treated in textbooks that have «tensor categories» or «monoidal categories» in their title.

Comment: I think that the category of vector spaces has a unique tensor structure in which the multiplication is the usual tensor product, soner cannot give examples there.